# Basic Maths in Swift

Tags: swift

Im very new to Xcode and am trying to make a simple app that calculates Gross Profit.

I am trying to use the following code but it returns the value '0'.

any ideas why?

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

var costPrice = 10

var salePrice = 100

var grossProfit = ((salePrice - costPrice) / salePrice) * 100

println(grossProfit)
```

Comment: Because you initialize your variables using integer literals, they get typed as integers. The subsequent division is thus integer division, which rounds down. You'll need to use a different approach (floating point or decimal types, scale your values up by a factor of 100, etc).

Comment: you have forgot to add the types for your variables, so basically they are _integers_ only – not _floats_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all explained in the first few pages of the iBook "Introduction to Swift" that is free and published by Apple.

Swift is type safe and will infer type from context.

The line `var costPrice = 10` is inferring that the variable `costPrice` is an int.

You then can't implicitly combine ints with other types of numbers (doubles for instance).

If you try this..

```
let costPrice = 10.0

let salePrice = 100.0

let grossProfit = ((salePrice - costPrice) / salePrice) * 100.0
```

You will find this works.

Answer (score 1):

`10` and `100` are integers, so `costPrice` and `salePrice` are integers. Integer division truncates as you're seeing. You wanted to use `10.0` and `100.0` here.