# Basic code that counts the number of digits in a given number, but why is it working?

Tags: swift, logic

I wrote this function but, while I'm happy it works, I don't seem to understand why.

This function just give us the number of digits in a given number passed in it. My question is: 
Since I'm only dividing a number by 10, shouldn't the while loop be infinite ? Since it will always be greater than 0. Example: if I pass in 250, it should be:

- 25; counter = 1

then

- 2.5 ; counter = 2

then

- 0.25; counter = 3

then

- 0.025; counter = 4

etc...

```
func count(_ num: Int) -> Int {
    var counter = 0
    var number = num
    while number > 0 {
        number = number / 10
        counter += 1
    }
    return counter
}
```

Comment: Integer division. The fraction is discarded.

Comment: Add `print(number)` to your while loop and you'll see  quickly that your theory is wrong.

Comment: If you wrote this function, why did you write it that way if you didn't expect it to work? It is doing integer division, so eventually you get 0 when dividing by 10.

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40579550/swift-print-decimal-precision-of-division.

Comment: @MartinR I know that my theory is wrong, otherwise I wouldn't have posted this question. I tried printing the number, it appears that when the number reaches 2 (when passing 250) and is divided by 10, it jumps directly to 0. Do you know why ?

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, just saw the question you sent, I understand now thank you!

Comment: Another one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26890394.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wont be an infinite loop because you are using an `Int`. Therefore, there is no rest of the division, that means that when you divide for example `2/10` , the result would be `0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in `Swift`, why don't you simply write,

```
let number = 250
let str = String(number)
print(str.count) //3
```

After all you want to `count the number of digits` in a given `Int value` right?